# Connecting Flights

Tags: international-travel, check-in, connecting-flights, code-share, iad

I will be flying from San Diego to Dubrovnik in July through SAS airlines. I booked my ticket through SAS and one of the domestic flights is being operated through United. I have a layover in Dulles (DC) and another one in Copenhagen. Will I be able to get all my flight info and tickets when I first check in in San Diego? Or do I have to get the rest of my information and tickets when I land in Dulles and recheck in? I am only concern with this because I have an 1 hour connecting time and I am really cutting it thin when it comes to time. Any information will be much appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

If you've purchased a single ticket for this entire trip, you should be able to check in at San Diego and receive all your boarding passes there (or quite possibly online if you check-in in advance). If there is somehow an issue with that, just speak to the gate agent at Dulles and they'll be able to print you a boarding pass.

With a single ticket, your bags will be checked through, and you won't need to return to the check-in counter at Dulles. You'll just need to walk to your next gate. An hour should be sufficient time unless there are delays.